# How to download a file from GoogleColab in python script?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a python script which creates a `.csv` file.

When I try downloading the file `Vectors.csv`(the file created by the code) within the script by

```
df.to_csv("Vectors.csv", sep=",", index=False)
files.download("Vectors.csv")
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Deep/makeVectors.py", line 52, in <module>
files.download("Vectors.csv")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/files.py", line 178, in download
'name': _os.path.basename(filename),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py", line 35, in eval_js
kernel = _ipython.get_kernel()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py", line 28, in get_kernel
return get_ipython().kernel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

Whereas when I type the same commands in Colab cells, it works fine.

Browser: Google Chrome

Answer (score 5):

The Google Colab team made a notebook covering uploading/downloading external data. One of the blocks is on [downloading files to the local system](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=hauvGV4hV-Mh).

Adapting their example to a Pandas Dataframe `df` saved as a csv file:

```
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv')

files.download('dataframe.csv')
```

A more specific example for OP's situation (running a Python script inside of a Colab cell): First the script

```
# makeVectors.py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv')
```

And the Colab cell

```
!python3 makeVectors.py

from google.colab import files
files.download('dataframe.csv')
```

This second example has some issues, in particular the extra features provided by `google.colab` package (as well as any regular iPython magic) will not work within the `python3` call.

Comment: I need to store a dataframe in csv so kindly suggest accordingly.

Comment: Andrew F this is the same thing I am doing, understand that I don't want to run it directly in a cell rather I have written my statements in a file and I run that file using `!python3 makeVectors.py`

Comment: Running the above snippet within a cell appears to work fine. If you instead have a `makeVectors.py` file that you want to execute within the Colab cell, then it makes sense that the inner `python3` command can't find the iPython kernel -- it has no kernel. You could change the `makeVectors.py` script to just save the csv file to the workspace, then inside of the Colab cell make the `files.download(...)` call.

Comment: Ok! Could you plz provide the code to save the file in the workspace?

Comment: @yaminigoel Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186867/discussion-between-andrew-f-and-yamini-goel).

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can download like that, as the code is ran in a remote machine (not in your own machine). But you can save the files in your Google Drive account and download from there.

Comment: how can I save the file in drive?

Comment: The other answer gives a pretty good link (cudos to Andrew F) : https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=RWSJpsyKqHjH